# How to reduce if else conditions in c

Tags: c

Actually I am trying to reduce the if else conditions but I am not getting how to do in C.

**for Example my code is**

```
 if(this.Index==1100 && this.SubIndex==1)
 {
 putValue(Com_stMECUErr,this.Data);
  }

 else if(this.Index==1100 && this.SubIndex==2)
  {
  putValue(B_sbbvk,this.Data);
   }

 else if(this.Index==1100 && this.SubIndex==3)
  {
 putValue(Com_bMSVIdle,this.Data);
   }

  // haivng 100 more similar conditions

   }
```

Answer (score 5):

If the values are in a continuous range:

```
yourtypehere subIndexValues[] = {whatever, Com_stMECUErr, B_sbbvk, Com_bMSVIdle};

if(this.Index==1100)
{
  putValue(subIndexValues[this.SubIndex],this.Data);
}
```

Or you can use a mixture of `if`s for the index, and `case`s/arrays for the specific ranges.

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of some of the redundancy like this:

```
if (this.Index == 1100)
{
    switch (this.SubIndex)
    {
        case 1:
            putValue(Com_stMECUErr, this.Data);
            break;
        case 2:
            putValue(B_sbbvk, this.Data);
            break;
        case 3:
            putValue(Com_bMSVIdle, this.Data);
            break;
        ...
        default:
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the SubIndex does not map to specific value, then use if or switch.

This is the if way.

```
if(this.Index == 1100) {
    if (this.SubIndex==1) putValue(Com_stMECUErr, this.Data);
    if (this.SubIndex==2) putValue(B_sbbvk, this.Data);
    if (this.SubIndex==3) putValue(Com_bMSVIdle,this.Data);
    // 100's more if's 
} else { //if this.Index != 1100
}
```

This is the switch way.

```
if(this.Index == 1100) {
    switch(this.SubIndex) {
        case 1: putValue(Com_stMECUErr, this.Data); break;
        case 2: putValue(B_sbbvk, this.Data); break;
        case 3: putValue(Com_bMSVIdle,this.Data); break;
        // 100's more cases
        default: break;
    }
    // 100's more if's 
} else { //if this.Index != 1100
}
```

If the SubIndex does map to specific value, then you can use array to do it the shortest way.

```
YourDataType values[] = {
    whatever, 
    Com_stMECUErr, 
    B_sbbvk, 
    Com_bMSVIdle, 
    hundredsmore
}
if(this.Index == 1100) {
    putValue(values[this.SubIndex], this.Data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (this.Index==1100) {
  if (this.SubIndex==1)
    putValue(Com_stMECUErr, this.Data);
  if (this.SubIndex==2)
    putValue(B_sbbvk, this.Data);
  if (this.SubIndex==3)
    putValue(Com_bMSVIdle,this.Data);
  // haivng 100 more similar conditions
}
```

or something like

```
if (this.Index==1100) {
  the_type_of_the_first_argument_of_putValue table1100[]= {
    Com_stMECUErr, // 1
    B_sbbvk,       // 2
    Com_bMSVIdle   // 3
    // haivng 100 more similar conditions
  };
  if (this.SubIndex<=no_of_entries_in_table1100)
    putValue(table1100[this.SubIndex-1], this.Data);
  else
    printf("value not found.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can check this.Index == 1100 once then use a switch statement to test for the subindex

i.e. since you have a common check in all the conditions you can extract it:

```
if (this.Index==1100){
  switch(this.Subindex){
    case 1:
      ...
    case 2:
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the code using the switch statement and by moving one if statement up:

```
if (this.Index == 1100) {
    switch(this.SubIndex) {
    case 1:
        putValue(Com_stMECUErr,this.Data);
        break;
    case 2:
        putValue(B_sbbvk,this.Data);
        break;
    case 3:
        putValue(Com_bMSVIdle,this.Data);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does each SubIndex map to a specific value?

In that case you could make a HashMap or someting similar which keeps track of the mappings. If you did that, whenever you have to check for the values you could do something like:

```
if(this.Index == 1100){
    putValue(someMap.get(this.SubIndex), this.Data);
}
```

Doing it this way could save you a lot of code, especially if you have to check the mappings multiple times in different parts of your code.