# Is there any way to reduce the IF statement without using the ternary operator?

Tags: c

This is a working code and m just asking that is it possible to reduce the if statement. can i code all the conditions in the single if statement ?

I tried to use the less if statements.

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, maximum;
    printf("Enter three numbers:");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    if ((a > b) && (a > c))
    {
        maximum = a;
    } 
    else if ((b > a) && (b > c)) 
    {
        maximum = b;
    }
    else {
        maximum = c;
    }
    printf("The Maximum among three is = %d", maximum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: common way of doing this is to have a `max` function, taking 2 arguments, and doing `max(max(a,b),c)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce if else conditions in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098298/how-to-reduce-if-else-conditions-in-c)

Comment: You have three different possible outcomes.  There is no way to choose deterministically among three outcomes via fewer than two binary decisions, though you could move one (or both) to a separate function, or express it via the ternary operator.

Comment: If overflow is not a concern, `maximum = (a+b+2*c + abs(a-b) + abs((a+b-2*c + abs(a-b))))/4;`. (`abs` is defined in `<stdlib.h>`.) You can also use `long int` or `long long int` with `labs` or `llabs` to avoid overflow in implementations where those are longer than `int`.

Comment: ot: your code doesn't work if `a == b` and `a > c`

Comment: @devanand: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 12):

You can simplify the code by reducing the comparisons:

```
maximum = a;
if(maximum < b) { maximum = b; }
if(maximum < c) { maximum = c; }
```

This would be same as loop unroll optimization, if you'd do the search on array.

Comment: This code is simpler and better than the OP's, but it does not answer the question: "can i code all the conditions in the single if statement ?"

Answer (score 2):

> m just asking that is it possible to reduce the if statement. can i
>   code all the conditions in the single if statement ?

If you must use only `if` statements to determine the maximum, not ternary expressions, arithmetic, or any other flow-control statement, then you cannot do it by executing fewer than two `if` statements. Each one selects between two outcomes, and you must provide for three different possible outcomes.

You can write *simpler conditions*, as some other answers demonstrate, but you cannot execute fewer `if` statements.

Alternatively, if you are permitted to loop, then you can have one `if` statement that is executed twice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (a < b) a = b;
    b = c;
}
maximum = a;
```

Or if you are permitted to use a `switch` statement then you can do it with zero `if` statements, using the fact that conditional expressions evaluate to either 0 or 1:

```
switch (((a >= b) << 2) | ((a >= c) << 1) | (b >= c)) {
    case (1 << 2) | (1 << 1) | 0:
    case (1 << 2) | (1 << 1) | 1:
        // (a >= b) and (a >= c) both evaluate to 1, so a is the maximum
        maximum = a;
        break;
    case (1 << 0):
        // a is not the maximum, and (b >= c) evaluates to 1, so b is the maximum
        maximum = b;
        break;
    default:
        maximum = c;
        break;
}
```

Note that the `switch` expression evaluates *three* conditional sub-expressions, not just two, but there are no `if` statements. The expressions in the case labels are evaluated at compile time, not runtime; they could be manually precomputed, but giving them in the above form better shows how the values are related to the `switch` expression.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57253126/2402272) hints at how you could use arithmetic alone to arrive at your result without any `if` statements (but nevertheless executing at least two conditional expressions).

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do I think is to reduce it to an if-elseif statement (i.e. removing the else block) by initialising `maximum` to `c`:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, maximum;
    printf("Enter three numbers:");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    maximum = c;
    if ((a > b) && (a > c))
    {
        maximum = a;
    } 
    else if ((b > a) && (b > c)) 
    {
        maximum = b;
    }
    printf("The Maximum among three is = %d", maximum);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I wouldn't necessarily recommend this though - your original code in my opinion is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty version without an `if` statement nor a ternary operator:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, c, maximum;
    printf("Enter three numbers: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);  // should test for success, but hope for the best
    maximum = (a >= b) * a + (a < b) * b;
    maximum = (maximum >= c) * maximum + (maximum < c) * c;
    printf("The Maximum among %d, %d and %d is %d\n", a, b, c, maximum);
    return 0;
}
```

The code still uses comparisons, but the compiler produces efficient code without jumps nor multiplications on many targets as can be verified using Godbolt's Compiler Explorer:  https://godbolt.org/z/65xKG4